# Filtering an object based on data available in another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am struggling with filtering an array of partners. Just for the sake of simplicity, I am defining partner object as below:

```
var partners = [
  { partnerCategory: "Gold", programs: ["Enterprise"] },
  { partnerCategory: "Silver", programs: ["Core", "Enterprise"] },
  { partnerCategory: "Silver", programs: ["Enterprise"] }
];
```

Now there are 2 picklists: partnerCategory and programs. If the user selects any value from the picklist, then I am populating an object filterCriteria.

Now I am defining filterCriteria in various ways to get an idea of the records that should be returned.

**OPTION 1**

```
var filterCriteria = [
   { fieldName: "partnerCategory", fieldValue: ["Silver"] }
];
```

2nd and 3rd record should be returned.

**OPTION 2**

```
var filterCriteria = [
   { fieldName: "partnerCategory", fieldValue: ["Silver", "Gold"] }
];
```

No record should be returned

**OPTION 3**

```
var filterCriteria = [
   { fieldName: "partnerCategory", fieldValue: ["Silver"] },
   { fieldName: "programs", fieldValue: ["Enterprise"] }
];
```

2nd and 3rd records should be returned.

**OPTION 4**

```
var filterCriteria = [
   { fieldName: "partnerCategory", fieldValue: ["Silver"] },
   { fieldName: "programs", fieldValue: ["Enterprise", "Core"] }
];
```

Only 2nd record should be returned.

So basically if a value is present in filterCriteria object, then the record should have all the values present in the filter.

I am using the below code to get the output, but I am missing something:

```
var result = partners.filter(function (obj) {
    return filterCriteria.every(function (c) {
        var value = obj[c.fieldName];
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            return Object.keys(value).every(function (key) {
                return c.fieldValue.indexOf(value[key]) > -1
            })
        }
        else
            return c.fieldValue.indexOf(value) > -1
    })
});
```

**EDIT: Now I am using this code, but option 2 and 4 are not giving the desired output:**

```
var result = partners.filter(function (partner) {
    return filterCriteria.every(function (c) {
        var value = partner[c.fieldName];
      console.log(value);
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
                return c.fieldValue.length==value.length && 
                c.fieldValue.every(function(v,i){return v==value[i];});
        }
        else
            return c.fieldValue.indexOf(value) > -1;
    })
})
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue?  Is it using a string to select the key for another object?  In what way do you have this implemented?  You state your expected results but never state what output you're getting.

Comment: The output is not coming properly when I change the data in filterCriteria. I have edited the post to let you know what am I doing to get the output.

Comment: In what way is it not coming out properly?  I ran it in jsfiddle and it seems to work fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/whdqah6m/

Comment: If 
var filterCriteria = [
   { fieldName: "partnerCategory", fieldValue: ["Silver"] },
   { fieldName: "programs", fieldValue: ["Enterprise", "Core"] }
];

Then only 2nd record should be displayed, not 2 records.

Also the jsfiddle link which u shared don't have the full code.

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: Yes, I did. I am still debugging. :(

Comment: I have modified my code, but option 2 and 4 are not working.